# Post Cross domain data not finding any working answer anywhere

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, cross-domain, shopify

Hey guyz i am new to stackoverflow community.I am facing a issue regarding cross domain request. Wheni get the data from other domain i can do it using jsonp but jsonp only get the data but when i try to post data using ajax in json format it is giving me cross-domain error in console. I have read many forums some stackoverflow solutions as well but nothing worked for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript   |  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877309/submit-cross-domain-ajax-post-request |  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984871/cross-domain-ajax-form-post-how-is-this-allowed | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322999/simple-ajax-post-with-cross-domain-request

Comment: Hey Ranjit any of the solution worked for you ?

Answer (score 1):

I do this "sort of" API calls, not product create just getting info, on a separate app on Heroku. Sinatra works fine.

Assuming you are using Ruby/Sinatra, do something like this on your Heroku/Whatever App:

```
    configure do
     $apikey = ENV['API_KEY']
     $password = ENV['PASSWORD']
     $shopname = ENV['SHOPNAME']
    end

post '/somepath' do
  puts params.inspect
  ShopifyAPI::Base.site = "https://#{$apikey}:#{$password}@#
  {$shopname}.myshopify.com/admin"
  my_variant = ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(variant_id)
  puts my_variant.inspect
  #or whatever you want to do
end
```

The approach is to construct your base site and then issue calls to the various API like this:

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.create(:handle => 'foo', :title => 'Foo')
```

You'll probably need more options, just look at the JSON docs and try and map them to the Ruby API library. You can always of course use raw JSON, but you'll need to handle the authentication which the shopify_api Ruby gem handles for you:

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api

Hope this helps.

You definitely want to avoid CORS/JSONP, they fail behind firewalls for customers, also silently with security add-ons, all sorts of ways. Very frustrating for them. Embedded, Proxy Apps are the way to go if you need to send something from your site via straight up JSON to an external app. All you need to do is create an embedded app, very easy with the Rails Gem and not too hard with the Sinatra one, there is also sample code on the Shopify site, and make it a proxy as well.

This means when your site submits to mystore.shopify.com/apps/some-path/some-otherpath it proxy passes through to myapp.heroku.com/some-otherpath or wherever your app is hosted.

But if you just need to touch Shopify to get products and stick them in a database, or modify them, or create them via some outside app, the above code will work for you with obviously some modifications.

Comment: Thanks Floyd for your answer may be your code is working but i am  php developer. I am not using Sinatra. I am using php.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't make cross domain ajax request. It is restricted. You have to use either api or jsonp. Your question is already answered at [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/).

Comment: but by using api you can get data is there any way i can post it. For instance take my situation. I am currently creating an app in shopify when i can use i get all products but when i post data to create product i am getting cross-domain error.

Comment: I explain you create an API that will provide cross domain users data in json. These cross domain users will consume your api to get your data. I think shopify is in php built, so you create api in php then your cross domain users can consume your api in jquery or php or asp or any other language.

Comment: Shopify is made in ROR framework . The thing is this is the 3rd time i am facing the issue. There are lot of apps and websites are doing same thing. For example : An app called oberlo in shopify doing exactly same thing i want to do. Take products using Aliexpress api and fetch it on there store then use shopify admin api to create product in shopify store from the app. HOw they are posting data cross-domain.

Comment: @DeveloperVise.. Give NodeJs and Back4App/Heroku a spin.. Or even a shell program..

Comment: I haven't use Nodejs yet but still if it is a js i will face this issue again of crossorigin scripts...

Comment: Anybody knows the answer please let me know.

Comment: The answer is simple. In any scripting language you care to use, make an authenticated POST to the API endpoint for product create, and your product will be created.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the simplest piece of the PUZZLE. You do not make Ajax Requests to your very own server from a Shopify store without using the App Proxy. If you have installed an App in the store, then you can use the App Proxy. Using the App Proxy, you can securely POST/GET to your endpoint at your domain, without CORS or that shockingly bad JSONP crap.

TL:DR; all your problems with Ajax disappear when you use the App Proxy.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the reply actually i am not making request from shopify to my app. I am making request from my app to shopify admin api to create product This is what i am trying to do .Click here https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product#create

Comment: Wow, You are one confused puppy! Good luck!

Comment: I am not confused i am clear what i want @David Lazar.

Comment: Well if you are making an authenticated POST to Shopify from your App, CORS/JSONP should never come into play so that is the answer to that. Creating a Product is a simple POST of JSON to Shopify. No more, no less, and has nothing to do with XHR or other problems you point out.

Comment: So what is the issue according to shopify api when i post as they say in their api https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product#create

Comment: You are making an XHR call when you should just be making a plain POST.